# ios 6 iphone app dont work in ipad

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios6

**Error in ios 6**

Here are the steps to generate the error

1. - Generate a project for iphone
2. - Add a button to the interface builder
3. - Run and build on the ipad simulator
4. - Press the button and it does not work. Except if you press 2x, or turn the iPad upside down position as the button works again and the app

Anyone know why this happens? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code solve the problem  =)

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{ 
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight; 

}
```

Comment: Can you delete your other duplicate answer?  Also in future it would be better if you simply edited your answer rather than create a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look closely at what you wrote here:

1. - Generate a project for iphone

You've have only created a project for the iPhone. You can change this setting in your Build Settings.

[image]

Comment: Thanks friend and try that. but i only need the proyect to iphone

But the problem persists.

  My application starts with the orientation landscape left and landscape right

And the button does not work

Comment: This code solve the problem 

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}